# Nonconstant index into instance array

Tags: system-verilog

SystemVerilog newbie here, I have an array of 2 APB Interfaces: `apb_if m_apb_if[0:1]` used for interfacing with harness in TB. Initially, I wrote tasks like this:

```
task foo;
input string DUT_name;
if (DUT_name == "DUT1") 
  ##1 m_apb_if[0].write...
else if (DUT_name == "DUT2")
  ##1 m_apb_if[1].write...
```

The code above works but 50% of it is redundant(imagine same thing on 20 if). I wanted to reduce tasks code length. I've tried:

```
task foo;
input string DUT_name;
int dut_number;
dut_number = set_name_number(DUT_name);//function returning int
##1 m_apb_if[dut_number].write... //this line fails
```

Passing int to task as input gives the same error when trying to invoke .write:

```
input int dut_name;
```

Does index to array has to be constant because it has to be known at the start of the simulation? How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes to an array of modules and interfaces need to be a constant. The work around is a virtual interface, which can have a dynamic index and points to a real interface.

```
apb_if m_apb_if[0:1]();
virtual apb_if m_apb_vif[0:1];
initial begin : map_physical2virtual
  m_apb_vif[0] = m_apb_if[0]; // Note: for-loop does not work here
  m_apb_vif[1] = m_apb_if[1]; // Index to phy-if must a constant
end : map_physical2virtual
...
task foo ( input string DUT_name);
  int dut_number;
  dut_number = set_name_number(DUT_name);//function returning int
  ##1 m_apb_vif[dut_number].write... // should work
endtask : foo
```

Your virtual interface can also be an associative array with the index being the dut's name

```
apb_if m_apb_if[0:1]();
virtual apb_if m_apb_vif[string];
initial begin : map_physical2virtual
  m_apb_vif["DUT1"] = m_apb_if[0]; // Note: for-loop does not work here
  m_apb_vif["DUT2"] = m_apb_if[1]; // Index to phy-if must a constant
end : map_physical2virtual
...
task foo ( input string DUT_name);
  if(!m_apb_vif.exists(DUT_name) begin
    // throw error or something
  end
  else begin
    ##1 m_apb_vif[dut_number].write... // should work
  end
endtask : foo
```

Comment: Just to add to Greg's answer. Arrays of instances need to be indexed with constants because they are no true arrays where each element has identical characteristics. Constructs like `defparam` and `generate` can make each index very different. The Verilog elaboration process essentially flattens out all hierarchy and creates names with what look like array indexes, but they are just part of the flattened name.